# Azure DevOps Server does not update pages with Live updates

Tags: devops

Since we updated from TFS to Azure DevOps Server 2020 we have a problem with live updates when using the client. I expect pages to automatically update with new information as they come available like it did with TFS, but that doesn't happened anymore. Instead we get an error:

'Live updates for this pull request were temporarily interrupted. Refresh to view the latest.'

[image]

I suspect it is a problem with a server setting, but I have no idea where to look.

Azure DevOps Server
Version Dev18.M170.4

Comment: Are you sure it's not a performance issue?
I only get that issue on occasion, and then it goes away.

Comment: Can you solve this problem?